# How to Remote validate email or check if email exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, email-validation, asp.net-4.5, remote-validation

I am trying to check if Email exists at registration so that there are no duplicate emails in the database. I am doing this with the MVC4 default Internet Application but i have added an Email field to the RegisterviewModel. I also noticed that, this is well done with UserName field but i have no idea how they did it. I tried to follow This blog below but no luck as there is no response when i click create. [Tug Berk](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/check-instantly-if-username-exists-asp-net-mvc-remote-validation). When i use firebug i am getting `Status: 302 Found` when `Json action excutes`

This is what i have have:

**UserProfile**

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**RegisterViewModel**

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [Remote("DoesUserEmailExist", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Email address already exists. Please enter a different Email address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.",      MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**Register Action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try //CreateUserAndAccount
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { model.Email });
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Json Action**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DoesUserEmailExist(string email)
    {

        var user = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(email);

        return Json(user == null);
    }
```

**Edit: Added Register View**

```
     @model Soccer.Models.RegisterModel

     @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Register";
     }

     <hgroup class="title">
     <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
     <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
     </hgroup>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary()

 <fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
 }

 @section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

Is there something i shouldn't be doing or is there another simpler option i could take here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starter, i would like to say thanks to [JOBG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118447/jobg) for intracting with me through this. What i showed in the question above should still work if you use `Database First` as it demands that you set Email column `UNIQUE` in the database, however to make it work with `EF Code First` i had to do the following to the register action, also note that with this solution, you don't need `Remote Annotation in the model`:

**Register Action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Insert a new user into the database
            using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
            {
                UserProfile email = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email.ToLower() == model.Email.ToLower());
                try
                {
                    // Check if email already exists
                    if (email == null)
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email });
                        WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email address already exists. Please enter a different email address.");
                    }
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Note:** Take note that this action validates Email before UserName and that it requires that you take a trip to the database atleast once before you create your object.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell without the View code but my first suspect is js, make sure you have jQuery validation plug-in set in place, it should be firing the validation with `.blur()` event,  inspect the page with firebug(or similar) and look for an ajax POST that hits `DoesUserEmailExist` when the field loses focus, if this is not happening then something is missing in client side as `Remote` attribute and the service  `DoesUserEmailExist` looks ok.

***Side Note***: Make sure you have the `UNIQUE` constraint in the database for the email field, this is the only real way to make sure you have no duplicate emails, even with the `DoesUserEmailExist` verification, because of concurrency.

Comment: I have added a Register view. As for UNIQUE constraint, i am not sure if that's possible with code first entity framework. Considering that, this has already been assigned to UserId

Comment: You are right EF5 does not support UNIQUE with code first argh, maybe that's one of the reasons why i don't use it, i prefer db first... as for the question, this bundle `~/bundles/jqueryval` renders the needed js so that's not the problem, did you try firebug to check for the request?

Comment: I just run it, `Status: 302 Found` That's what i got, something is definitely wrong here

Comment: Just a quick notice, i just realised that under Post only the first letter of the email string is assigned to Email. Should it be like that? `Email=k`

Comment: 302 Found, there is something wrong with your route, is the action and controller name correct in Remote Attribute? if you put a breakpoint in your `DoesUserEmailExist` Does it gets hit?

Comment: Well, everything is noted above in the question. I think its all there

Comment: Mmm looking again 302 is a redirect. Is `DoesUserEmailExist` behind some authentication? Maybe you are missing `[AllowAnonymous]`...

Comment: Well, i looked into `[AllowAnonymous]` no luck. Is there a difference between `WebSecurity.cs` and `Membership.cs` because if you look at register action, we are calling `WebSecurity.cs` while in Json action `Membership.cs` is called. After all the tries, i feel as though the problem is bewteen those 2 classes.

Comment: I just realised something, this method demands that the column in the table is set to UNIQUE.....i may need to find a different method to achieve what i want.

Comment: +1 for sticking around, thanks alot. What i did works with `Database First`. The solution i just posted works with `EF Code First`, atleast to my knowledge